# ¿Agregar Angular JS 2 a los snippets?

Tags: característica-nueva, stack-snippets

Esto es una propuesta, no conozco mucho del tema sobre *Angular JS*, pero ahora que la gente está trabajando con ***Angular JS, en la versión 2***, estaría bueno que en los snippets aparezca como opción.

[image: Angular JS 2]

También, la verdad no sé cómo lo tomaría la gente, pero estaría bueno que en vez de decir **AngularJS 1.2.23**, diga solo **1.2.23**, y el texto **AngularJS** quede a la izquierda del cuadro de selección, en mi opinión queda un poco feo.

Otra alternativa puede ser, varios cuadros de selección, si elige No **AngularJS**, no pasa nada, pero si elige que sí, aparece otro cuadro, diciendo, **1** y **2**... Si elige **1** aparece otro diciendo, **2.23**, **2.22**.

Comment: Relacionado: [Can we have newer versions of third-party libraries in the Stack Snippets tool?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333042/5290909) *(sin respuesta)*; aunque quizás no incluyan versiones beta...  Mientras tanto, siempre está la opción de hacer click en el botón `[Añadir librería externa]` y agregar el CDN.